# Distinct Certain Key Object

Tags: c#, dictionary

i have this certain Key in my Dictionary:

```
public class KKey
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Guid Guid { get; set; }
}

Dictionary<KKey, string> myDictionary = new Dictionary<KKey, string>();
```

problem was everytime I generate new Guid, this condition wouldnt work:

```
if (false == myDictionary.TryGetValue(key, out keyobj))
```

because Guid key was new ...

Now my question was, how can i make condition that verify if Kkey.Name was already added, then dont add?

Comment: I'm curious, what are you storing in the string part of the dictionary?

Comment: You need to make `KKey` implement `IEquatable<KKey>`. You might also want to make it a `struct` and have the properties be read-only after construction, as modifying dictionary keys is something you really don't want to do.

Comment: @Jessica, just a description of the Name

Comment: I'm struggling to understand why you're making the Guid part of the key if Name is already meant to be unique.

Comment: @Jon, though my keys arent readOnly, but im not modifying it ... im just recreating instance of KKey to create a new key ...

Comment: So you are saying that two keys should be considered to match if they have the same Name property? What about case-sensitivity?

Comment: @Jessica, i guess I'll just transfer GUID property to value instead to key ... just uses GUID to key to match certain data from other collection ... but it gets worst! ... thanks for enlighten me . I'll just transfer it ... +1ty

Comment: Though I'll still accept the right answer if someone has it ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You either need to create a custom comparer or have your class override `Equals` and `GetHashCode`

Option 1: Comparer

```
sealed class NameEqualityComparer : IEqualityComparer<KKey>
{
    public bool Equals(KKey x, KKey y)
    {
        return string.Equals(x.Name, y.Name);
    }

    public int GetHashCode(KKey obj)
    {
        return (obj.Name != null ? obj.Name.GetHashCode() : 0);
    }
}

Dictionary<KKey, string> myDictionary = new Dictionary<KKey, string>(new NameEqualityComparer());
```

Option 2: Override

```
public class KKey : IEquatable<KKey>
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Guid Guid { get; set; }

    public bool Equals(KKey other)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(null, other)) return false;
        if (ReferenceEquals(this, other)) return true;
        return string.Equals(Name, other.Name);
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        return Equals(obj as KKey);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return (Name != null ? Name.GetHashCode() : 0);
    }
}

Dictionary<KKey, string> myDictionary = new Dictionary<KKey, string>();
```

Comment: @Elegiac you could use this approach to make Name case-insensitive but I do think that the Guid would be best put in the value instead of the key as it doesn't form part of the identity for the key.

Answer (score 0):

can also be

```
bool alreadyAdded = keywordList.Any(n => n.Key.Name == name);
if (!alreadyAdded) { }
```

Comment: While this code sample may possibly answer the question, it would be preferable to include some essential explanation to your answer. As it stands now this answer adds little to no value for future readers.